# Regional Indicator Emojis are not working fine in android

Tags: android, emoji

I have implemented the emojis in one of my application using this library on git hub

[Emojis](https://github.com/Hall/androidemojimap)

Everything is working fine for android to ios and vice-versa. But the regional flags are not working. When I send japan flag from IOS to android ,it woks fine but from android to ios it shows ????. This is happening because the regional indicators emojis are not define in EmojiMapUtil.java .I have added the code for regional indicator emojis in EmojiMapUtil.java file as follows:-

```
    {":jp:"                                ,new String(Character.toChars(0x1F1F5))},
    {":kr:"                                ,new String(Character.toChars(0xE514))},
    {":de:"                                ,new String(Character.toChars(0xE50E))},
    {":cn:"                                ,new String(Character.toChars(0xE513))},
    {":us:"                                ,new String(Character.toChars(0xE50C))},
    {":fr:"                                ,new String(Character.toChars(0xE50D))},//
    {":es:"                                ,new String(Character.toChars(0xE511))},
    {":it:"                                ,new String(Character.toChars(0xE50F))},
    {":ru:"                                ,new String(Character.toChars(0xE512))},
    {":gb:"                                ,new String(Character.toChars(0xE510))},
```

Anyone who use this library getting such type of issue? Please let me know and how to solve it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bravo!!!! :)
I got the solution of my own question by using some little bit brain...
Just wrote these lines instead of previous and now each and every emoji is working perfectly.

```
    {":j"                                  ,new String(Character.toChars(0x1F1EF))},
    {"p:"                                  ,new String(Character.toChars(0x1F1F5))},
    {":jp:"                                ,new String(Character.toChars(0xE50B))},

    {":k"                                  ,new String(Character.toChars(0x1F1F0))},
    {"r:"                                  ,new String(Character.toChars(0x1F1F7))},
    {":kr:"                                ,new String(Character.toChars(0xE514))},

    {":d"                                  ,new String(Character.toChars(0x1F1E9))},
    {"e:"                                  ,new String(Character.toChars(0x1F1EA))},
    {":de:"                                ,new String(Character.toChars(0xE50E))},

    {":c"                                  ,new String(Character.toChars(0x1F1E8))},
    {"n:"                                  ,new String(Character.toChars(0x1F1F3))},
    {":cn:"                                ,new String(Character.toChars(0xE513))},

    {":u"                                  ,new String(Character.toChars(0x1F1FA))},
    {"s:"                                  ,new String(Character.toChars(0x1F1F8))},
    {":us:"                                ,new String(Character.toChars(0xE50C))},

    {":f"                                  ,new String(Character.toChars(0x1F1EB))},//
    {"r:"                                  ,new String(Character.toChars(0x1F1F7))},//
    {":fr:"                                ,new String(Character.toChars(0xE50D))},//

    {":e"                                  ,new String(Character.toChars(0x1F1EA))},
    {"s:"                                  ,new String(Character.toChars(0x1F1F8))},
    {":es:"                                ,new String(Character.toChars(0xE511))},

    {":i"                                  ,new String(Character.toChars(0x1F1EE))},
    {"t:"                                  ,new String(Character.toChars(0x1F1F9))},
    {":it:"                                ,new String(Character.toChars(0xE50F))},

    {":r"                                  ,new String(Character.toChars(0x1F1F7))},
    {"u:"                                  ,new String(Character.toChars(0x1F1FA))},
    {":ru:"                                ,new String(Character.toChars(0xE512))},

    {":g"                                  ,new String(Character.toChars(0x1F1EC))},
    {"b:"                                  ,new String(Character.toChars(0x1F1E7))},
    {":gb:"                                ,new String(Character.toChars(0xE510))},
```

Write this code in EmojiMapUtil.java, remove the duplicate unicoded and all the regional indicator emojis will work fine for cross platform. Enjoy.. :)